# How to enable gravatar in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

How to enable gravatar in TortoiseGit?

I expect author's head in log.

It is a new function AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am talking about TortoiseGit 1.8.6

If you want to enable Gravatar for all repositories,

go to `TortoiseGit Settings` -> `General` -> `Dialogs 1`. Tick `Enable Gravatar`.

If you want to enable Gravatar for just one repository,

go to `Show Log` -> `View` -> tick `Gravatar`.

[image: Settings Dialogs 1]

Comment: Might need to clear up `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\TortoiseGit` folder.